# i can't boot to windows after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

i had windows 10 and installed Ubuntu as dual boot
after installing Ubuntu works fine but when i try to boot on windows in the grub menu it brings me to the grub menu again [i get this after using sudo updtae-grub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ShhT.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F73UX.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb2NE.png)

Comment: It says that there is an error on line 327 of a grub configuration file. Which file could that be (probably `init-select.cfg`) and what is on line 327?

Comment: how do i check ?

Comment: `cd /etc/default/grub.d/` and do `more init-select.cfg`. That file should be very short and not do anything on modern Ubuntu versions. So how can there be a line 327 with a syntax error?

Comment: i get this after using the commands :



mohax@MohaXsEpicPC:~$ cd /etc/default/grub.d/
mohax@MohaXsEpicPC:/etc/default/grub.d$ more init-select.cfg
# Work around a bug in the obsolete init-select package which broke
# grub-mkconfig when init-select was removed but not purged.  This file does
# nothing and will be removed in a later release.
#
# See:
#   https://bugs.debian.org/858528
#   https://bugs.debian.org/863801
mohax@MohaXsEpicPC:/etc/default/grub.d$

Comment: Please don't put the content of files in a comment. Edit your question and add it there, for readability.

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: OK so `init-select.cfg` is not the file causes an error, as it consists of comments. What other files are in that directory that may contain errors? Perhaps `/etc/default/grub` itself? Otherwise, look at line 327 of the generated config file, by doing `sudo nl /boot/grub/grub.cfg | more`. ( The `nl` command puts a line number before your lines).

Comment: i edited the question with what it shows after using the command

Comment: Don't paste screenshots into your question. Copy and paste the text itself, please. And don't remove information posted previously, like the error message.

Comment: @mohax And I know it's a lot to get used to when you are posting here for the first time, but we also ask that you not include text files as images.  Please see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) for many reasons why.  Please do [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1446405/edit) your question to include the text contents in the question itself.  You should place this in a code-block (see the [formatting help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)).  Thanks!

Comment: Does Winfows boot directly from UEFI boot menu? Grub only boots working Windows. And you also need fast startup off and bitlocker off. If always directly booting from UEFI boot menu, not grub, you can turn those back on, but will not be able to read any NTFS formatted partitions.

Comment: i tried changing the bios settings but couldn't find fast startup option or bitlocker

also when i turn on the pc it shows a grub menu with ubuntu and ubuntu advanced option and windows 10 that doesn't boot